# How to make sure border boxes auto adjust to window size in react

Tags: css, reactjs, window, size, border

I have been adding borders to text on react but run into problem wheer if window size is decreased the borders do not fit.  What is the property to have these adjust.

I attached two pictures to better explain problem.[normal sizing of borders with full window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG6Wo.png)

[reduced size of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IPzA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css you are looking for is display:block